# SmartOS issues after a minor incident

Tags: illumos

Last week I had issue where SmartOS wouldn't boot suddenly, it just hanged there after "mDNSPlatformRawTime went backwards by 3684530 ticks..." warning. I think this one always appears but I didn't pay attention, its just that it would hang at this point. Then since my zpool didnt contain that much important data, I just unplugged this disk and used another one to create fresh pool, as I thought maybe the disk is the issue (was on cheaper end).

Long story short, because its dual-boot, in Windows 7 I noticed that out of 6 sticks of RAM(12 GB), it sees only 2GBs, one stick. Today I got the time, and cleaned up dust plus there was some hair, and there we go, 12GB back, so I definitely think this was the issue.

But when I get back to smartos and even on new zpool/disk, when I try to install latest bootstrap, it says that root / filesystem is full.

I have not yet mastered Illumos/SmartOS, even though its my plan to delve as far as possible, so I'm not aware of how metadata on specific Zpool works, or what part is changed on USB boot stick itself, after kernel panic.. I remember this message from previous pool:
https://illumos.org/msg/FMD-8000-2K

Now, is it possible that on new zpool I still have to locate disabled module and enable it? Assuming all this was related to RAM incident when only 2GB was connected.

UPDATE:

so this is waht worries me, why is ramdisk:a such low capacity and full:

```
# df -h
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
/devices/ramdisk:a     289M   289M        66K   100%    /
/devices                  0      0          0     0%    /devices
/dev                      0      0          0     0%    /dev
ctfs                      0      0          0     0%    /system/contract
proc                      0      0          0     0%    /proc
mnttab                    0      0          0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                  4.76G   980K      4.76G     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                     0      0          0     0%    /system/object
bootfs                    0      0          0     0%    /system/boot
sharefs                   0      0          0     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/devices/pseudo/lofi@1:disk
                       432M   360M      72.4M    84%    /usr
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1
                       432M   360M      72.4M    84%    /lib/libc.so.1
```